# Java - why System and Runtime classes have identical methods?

Tags: java, api, runtime, system

I was wondering recently why do both `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.lang.System` have the same methods for library loading, garbage collecting and similar operations. Is it because of historical reasons, for convenience, or they really differ? Both classes are available from JDK 1.0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System exposes various things it might be appropriate for a developer to use the System for.

I would be concerned about a programmer playing directly with the Runtime.  For System to call the methods, they need to be exposed.

System provides an interface to the Runtime to enable access to Runtime methods that are appropriate to be called by programmers.  Call the System methods and let them delegate appropriately.

Comment: I don't understand what you'd like to express. If java don't want developers to play with Runtime directly, it should make it private instead of public. In reality, we can call Runtime's methods freely.

Comment: @Richard  The Runtime class exposes the underlying JVM and OS environment in ways that may not be portable.  The System class exposes a consistent portable view of JVM and OS. Runtime can't be private as a number of classes, including System, need to call it.   There are also limited cases where calling the methods directly may be appropriate.

Comment: You mean we should always prefer to use System class, if possible? Shortcut methods may be a good idea somewhere, but the API design like this is really confusing.

Comment: @Richard Yes. In any language there are usually ways to access the Runtime, but in general programming, it is best to use the provided System abstraction. Documentation and examples usually guide you to the abstraction.

Comment: @BillThor could you provide references for the portability?

Answer (score 4):

My guess (remember, its a guess), is that methods in the `System` class are there for convenience. For example, `System.gc();` is static, where `Runtime.gc();` is an instance method. This makes the call easier to make, since you don't need to obtain a `Runtime` instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for example at the method `System#load(String)`, you see, that it calls the method `Runtime#load(String)`. Same for `gc()`. So it is most probably for historical reasons.

Comment: I disagree for the historical argument. If you take a look at the Java 1.0 API, you will find, that the methods have always been present in System and Runtime.